# 3SUM: avoid duplicates

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Problem:
Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

To avoid duplicates I use an if-clause in the while loop, and I was wondering why this does not work. Thanks!

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    Arrays.sort(nums);

    for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1]){
            continue;
        }
        int target = -1*nums[i];
        int start = i+1;
        int end = nums.length-1;

        while (start < end){

            if (nums[start] == nums[start+1]){
                start++;
            } 

            if (nums[end] == nums[end--]){
                end--;
            } 

            if (nums[start]+nums[end] == target){
                System.out.printf("found");
                List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                temp.add(nums[i]);
                temp.add(nums[start]);
                temp.add(nums[end]);
                result.add(temp);
                start++;
                end--;
            } else if (nums[start]+nums[end] < target) {
                start++;
            } else {
                end--;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
```

I was testing on [-1,0,1] and my code returned an empty list. I tried to debug and printed some messages, and it seems that when i=1, in the while loop, it first enters

```
if (nums[start] == nums[start+1]){
                start++;
}
```

But nums[start] does not equal to nums[start+1] when start=1. This is quite bizzare. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace string in your code from

```
if (nums[end] == nums[end--]) {
```

to

```
 if (nums[end] == nums[end - 1]) {
```

Comment: Oh I just noticed that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

i decide to make a try))

```
package com.three.sum;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[]{-1, 0, 1};
        List<int[]> res = threeSum(nums);
        System.out.println(res.toString());
    }


    public static List<int[]> threeSum(int[] origNums) {
        List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        // ++ Use set to avoid duplicates
        Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int k  = 0; k < origNums.length; k++){
            intSet.add(origNums[k]);
        }
        // -- Use set to avoid duplicates

        Integer[] nums = intSet.toArray(new Integer[intSet.size()]);

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int target = - nums[i];
            int start = i + 1;
            int end = nums.length - 1;

            while (start < end) {
                if (nums[start] + nums[end] == target) {
                    int temp[] = new int[3];
                    temp[0] = nums[i];
                    temp[0] = nums[start];
                    temp[0] = nums[end];
                    result.add(temp);
                    start++;
                    end--;
                } else if (nums[start] + nums[end] < target) {
                    start++;
                } else {
                    end--;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! That's a good idea! But this solution does not include the case [0,0,0], otherwise it works fine (I should have stated the problem more clearly). I was still wondering what is wrong with my previous code